# Explode a pandas column containing a dictionary into new rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with one column being dictionaries of different lengths.

It looks something like this

```
   Chrom   POS   N_Allels   dict

0      1   345   2010       {"A":0.1,"T":0.22,"G":0.01}
1      1   357   1989       {"T":0.9}
2      1   365   1850       {"A":0.3,"G":0.2}
```

I want to explode the dict into two columns, creating a new row for each entry, resulting in something that looks like this

```
   Chrom   POS   N_Allels   base   freq

0      1    345   2010       "A"    0.1
1      1    345   2010       "T"    0.22
2      1    345   2010       "G"    0.01
3      1    357   1989       "T"    0.9
4      1    365   1850       "A"    0.3
5      1    365   1850       "G"    0.2
```

Is there a good, clean way to do that?

I know there exists the df.explode() function, but it only creates a new row for each key of the dict, not the value.

Comment: Here is the answer to you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows

Comment: They suggest the df.explode() method. As I mentioned this does not work, since it simply drops the respective value for the key. In general this method creates a row for each entry in the list/dict. But I want a conditional split into two columns, one for the key, one for the value

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
df_result = (
    df
    .assign(dict=df.dict.map(lambda d: d.items()))
    .explode("dict")
    .assign(
        base=lambda df: df.dict.str.get(0),
        freq=lambda df: df.dict.str.get(1)
    )
    .drop(columns="dict")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

First replace the dictionaries with the resp. `.items()` iterators, then explode the `dict` column, and afterwards divide the tuples in two columns `base` (index 0) and `freq` (index 1).

Result for the sample:

```
   Chrom  POS  N_Allels base  freq
0      1  345      2010    A  0.10
1      1  345      2010    T  0.22
2      1  345      2010    G  0.01
3      1  357      1989    T  0.90
4      1  365      1850    A  0.30
5      1  365      1850    G  0.20
```

Comment: This works. As mentioned by @Georg B in his comment, the direct application of `explode` does not work. `explode` uses the default iteration over the dictionary which corresponds to iteration over keys, thus values are lost. This approach from @Timus works because `assign(dict=df.dict.map(lambda d: d.items()))` overrides the default iteration over the dictionary and makes both keys and values available for `explode`.